# How to get println to print out in the Bamboo logs when running maven test goal

Tags: maven, junit, bamboo

I'm trying to work out how to print to the Bamboo logs from my JUnit test to debug a particular issue. I've tried using `System.out.println` and have even tried log4j but unfortunately neither are printing out in the Bamboo logs. I'm looking specifically at the log within a run.

My JUnit tests are being run from a Maven 3.0.4 task within a Plan defined in Bamboo.

I am able to see exceptions that have occurred within a test. However why can't I see anything that is done through `System.out.println`? How can I find out where this is being output to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Turned out that my pom.xml file I had the redirectTestOutputToFile option set to true. After removing this line all the logs now appear in Bamboo.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```